# SQL - Get Count of users with average age in range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know this should be painfully simple, but I'm having a mental block. I have three tables in a SQL Server 2008 database:

**Users:**

- ID
- Birthdate (datetime)

**User_Visits:**

- Site_ID
- User_ID
- Visit_Date

**Sites:**

- ID

I need a SQL statement that gets the count of sites that have visitors with an average age between say 40-50 years old.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) as SiteCount
from (
      select avg(datediff(year, U.BirthDate, UV.Visit_Date)) as AvgAge
      from Users as U
        inner join User_Visits as UV
         on U.ID = UV.User_ID
      group by UV.Site_ID   
     ) as T
where AvgAge >= 40 and
      AvgAge < 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try:

```
SELECT siteID, AVG(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(birthdate)) as avg_age,
FROM users_visits JOIN users ON users.ID = users_visits.userID 
GROUP BY siteID HAVING avg_age BETWEEN 40 AND 50
```

This would return all the sites that you are interested in. To get just the count, you need to put `count(siteID)` in `SELECT` part and move the definition of `avg_age` to the HAVING clause.